# In Azure to get getting list of role Assignments using python

Tags: python, azure

I am trying to get the azure role assignment in a subscription by using python. By following code

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.authorization import AuthorizationManagementClient
tenant_id = 'tenant_guid'
application_id = 'application_guid'
application_secret = 'application_secret'
cred = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=application_id, secret=application_secret, tenant=tenant_id)
client = AuthorizationManagementClient(cred, 'subscription_guid')
roles = client.role_assignments.list()
for role in roles:
print(role)
```

Exception: CloudError("The client 'XXXX-XXXX-xxxxxx' with object id 'XXXX-XXXX-xxxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/read' over scope '/subscriptions/XXXX-XXXX-xxxxxx'.",)

but , i am getting a authentication exception while running python code snippet though i am the admin of that service principal.

Could any one please help on finding this.

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Admin of the Service Principal does not mean your Service Principal is admin :). The message is clear that your service principal does not have the permission to do this operation.

See the built-in role in Azure:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles

In order to do an operation on 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/read', the SP (not you) needs to be 'Owner' or 'Reader' or 'API Management Service Contributor
', etc. (look the pattern in the list to know what roles authorize this operation).

You can then add a role to your SP using the portal:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role

or the CLI

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#manage-service-principal-roles